Issue when creating a new user and group on macOS
I need to create a user and a group called postgres on my mac but I seem to have issues with that. The reason for needing this user is because I've installed postgresql@15 via brew and it created a user called _postgres instead of postgres and the code I need to run doesn't recognize that.
I have created the use, the group and assigned the the user to the group as stated here with the following commands:
sudo dscl . -create /Groups/postgres
sudo dscl . -create /Users/postgres
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a postgres -t user postgres

Now, assuming that they have been successfully created, I tried changing ownership of a directory to this new user and group
sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/pgsql/15/data

but I get error
chown: postgres: illegal group name

I tried doing some investigation:
dscl . -read /Groups/postgres

and based on the output, it seems fine (output is good for checking /Users/postgres too:
dsAttrTypeNative:record_daemon_version: 8980000
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: 2A3120F5-BCC7-44EC-B0D6-97D680D49A88
GroupMembers: E4734A87-418E-43A6-AD42-783A7F1C2FF5
GroupMembership: postgres
RecordName: postgres
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Groups

However, running
id -g postgres

outputs:
id: postgres: no such user

It's also worth noting that the user and group don't appear in /etc/passwd.
Why is this happening and how can I get the user and group created properly?

I think your problem is that despite what the linked post says, a mere dscl . -create /Users/username is insufficient to create a working user. For one thing, it is missing a UID (attribute UniqueID).
The other is that for id to work, your user must have a PrimaryGroupID. That's what id -g does -- it displays the primary group id of the user.
But what's the GID? In your example you want to set it to the GID of the postgres group, but your dscl . -create command didn't give it one.
I would suggest using dseditgroup to create your group, since you can define it with the desired GID in one command:
sudo dseditgroup -q -i <gid> -o create postgres

where <gid> is an unused group id. (You can use dscl . -list /Groups PrimaryGroupID to list all of the existing groups with their ids. I would suggest picking a GID in the range 100-499, so it won't appear in System Settings Users & Groups.)
Then create your user, give it a UID, and the primary GID:
sudo dscl . -create /Users/postgres
sudo dscl . -create /Users/postgres UniqueID <uid>
sudo dscl . -create /Users/postgres PrimaryGroupID <gid>

where <uid> is an unused UID, and <gid> is the GID you gave your group. You can use dscl . -list /Users UniqueID to see which UIDs are in use.
Now you can add it to the group membership:
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a postgres -t user postgres

